# Get single element from Ruby range

Tags: ruby, range

I'm trying to print a single element from an array of 500 numbers. I initialized it using

```
arr = (1..500)
```

I can print from `for` loops:

```
for n in arr
  print n +"\n"
end
```

I can print using `arr.each`, but if I try to just grab one element I get an error.

```
print arr[0]
>undefined method `[]' for 1..500:Range (NoMethodError)
```

If I initialize an array `arr2 = ["a", "b", "c"]` and try to grab a single element that way it works fine.

I am assuming it is because of the way I initialized it (using the range) but eveywhere I look they say that is how you should initialize an array of numbers.

Is there any way for me to get a single element from my array?

Comment: Honestly, you should learn how to read error messages. Yours was telling you that you had a Range object, which doesn't have the `[]` method you were trying to use on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not a Array, it's a Range. You can convert it to an Array using `to_a`:

```
range = 0..500
arr   = range.to_a

puts arr[7] # => 6
```

Comment: Thanks! I figured it was something like that

Comment: In the future, you can tell what class something is by doing `puts object.class`.  I highly recommend playing around with this stuff in IRB until you are familiar with the language.

Comment: It seems wasteful to convert a Range into an Array to get a value at an "index" (what if it represents 2 billion numbers?) -- isn't there a more elegant way that can operate in constant time?

Comment: @pst Assuming you know the step size is `1`, you could just do `range.first + (7 - 1)`, though that's not super-elegant (unless you encapsulate it in a method).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it without converting the whole thing into array.

```
class Range
  def index(n)
    return nil unless n < self.size
    self.each_with_index { |x, i| return x if i == n }
  end
end

range = 0..100000000000
range.index(120) # => 120
```